# warning: format '%lu' expects argument of type 'long unsigned int', but argument 4 has type 'long unsigned int *' [-Wformat]

Tags: c, arrays, linux, pointers, printf

I get `warning: format '%lu' expects argument of type 'long unsigned int', but argument 4 has type 'long unsigned int *' [-Wformat]` for the code below

```
unsigned long  buf[254];
char systemlogmsg[500]= {'\0'};
snprintf(systemlogmsg, sizeof(systemlogmsg), "INFO: %lu ",  buf);
```

what should I have used instead of `%lu`?

Furthermore, I tried to use

```
snprintf(systemlogmsg, sizeof(systemlogmsg), "INFO: %lu ", (unsigned long int *) buf);
```

but it did not help. How should I have passed the cast?

Comment: What exactly do you want to do, print the 254 values, the first value, The address of the array?

Comment: I want to print all 254 values

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
unsigned long  buf[254];
```

declares an array of unsigned longs. So `buf` is a pointer as far as sprintf is concerned. But you are trying to format `%lu`, which expects not a pointer, perhaps an element of the array:

```
snprintf(systemlogmsg, sizeof(systemlogmsg), "INFO: %lu ",  buf[0]);  // ok
```

So, if you have 254 unsigned longs, you need to decide which one to print. If you want to print them all:

```
int s = 0, i;
for (i=0; i< 254; i++)
  s+=snprintf(systemlogmsg+s, 
       sizeof(systemlogmsg)-s, "INFO: %lu ",  buf[i]);  // ok
```

Comment: When you pass it to `sprintf()`, it's still an array. It's just that it decays into a pointer to its first element, and the function receives the pointer value.

Comment: 'When you pass it to sprintf(), it's still an array' -- this is a semantic quibble, and it's mostly wrong ... you can't pass arrays to C functions, so what is passed is actually the decayed pointer, not `buf`.

Answer (score 2):

I think the issue here is that `buf` is an *array* of `unsigned long`s, but you're passing in a formatting specifier that expects a *single* `unsigned long`.  You should either select the specific `unsigned long` out of the array that you want to print, or change the formatting specifier to print out a *pointer* rather than an `unsigned long`.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 2):

`buf` is an array of 254 `unsigned long`s and decays into `unsigned long *` when passed to a function. You have to decide which element of the array you want to print and use array subscripting:

```
snprintf(systemlogmsg, sizeof(systemlogmsg), "INFO: %lu ",  buf[0]);
```

for example.

Edit: if you want to print out all the 254 numbers, then you need to call the function in a loop (the array index being the loop variable, obviously).